# C# Expression Casting as Derived Type

Tags: c#, lambda, casting, expression

Using

```
IQueryable<T> query - where T : BaseEntity
```

I have the following code, used in a generic method - which uses reflection  to call the .Where() method (this is working):

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda(body, item);
MethodInfo whereCall = (typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == "Where" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(query.ElementType));
MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(whereCall, new Expression[] { query.Expression, predicate });

query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
```

I would like to use something like this (and avoid reflection):

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

But the problem with this code is that T is used as the base-type, and not the derived-type *at run-time*.

How can I cast T as query.ElementType (the derived type) ?

Comment: What if there are multiple derived types?

Comment: There will be, but you can get the derived type by using query.ElementType

Comment: I still don't understand the scenario. Somehow the code seems incomplete.

Comment: Why doesn't this code work as it stands?

Comment: @usr It does, I just want to get away from using reflection. I have updated the question further explaining.

Comment: Since your generic method has a generic argument `T`, accepts and returns `IQueryable<T>`, `query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);` and `query = query.Where(predicate);` are equivalent. `query.ElementType ` doesn't matter, you should be calling **your** generic method with a correct `T` (a concrete derived type satisfying your generic constraint). If you don't know the `T`, then your method should not be generic and should accept/return non generic `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second piece of code is indeed better than the first one. You will need to invoke the `Expression.Lambda` method using reflection *somehow*. A convenient way to do that is this:

```
static IQueryable<T> CreateQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, ...) {
  var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
  query = query.Where(predicate);
  return query;
}
```

Invoke this method using T as the derived type. You can perform that call using `MakeGenericMethod`. Depending on your scenario it might be enough to say:

```
CreateQuery((dynamic)query);
```

Comment: This works, I will mark it as the correct answer if no one is able to provide a better solution by not creating another method/not casting as dynamic.